# JSONB integer array contains value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table Directory like below with jsonb column

```
id: 1
folder:
  {"file_ids"=>[639,12,28]},
 options:{}

id: 2
folder:
  {"file_ids"=>[28]},
options:{}

id: 3
folder:
  {"file_ids"=>[12]},
options:{}

id: 4
folder:
 "file_ids"=>[639]},
options:{}
```

How we query all directories which contain any of file ids with 12,28, when trying below code it is always throwing error?

```
Directory.where("directories.folder->>'file_ids' = ANY(ARRAY[?]::int[])", [12,28])
```

I need the result:

```
    id: 1
    folder:
      {"file_ids"=>[639,12,28]},
     options:{}

    id: 2
    folder:
      {"file_ids"=>[28]},
    options:{}

    id: 3
    folder:
      {"file_ids"=>[12]},
    options:{}
```

Is there any other way to query details?

Comment: “is always throwing error”—what error?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] = character varying
LINE 1: ...directories.folder->'file_ids')::varchar[]) = ANY(ARRA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got one solution,

I have converted all integer value to the string  ['12','28']

```
Directory.where("directories.folder->>'file_ids' ~* any (ARRAY[?])", ['28','12'])
```